# Vue/Nuxt static deployment - render time of styles

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, server-side-rendering

I am facing the following issue:
A vue/nuxt when deployed in static mode requires visibly longer time to load the Vuetify component styles (colors etc).

Components are first loaded with default graphite color (dark grey) and after about half a second they acquire their templated colors.
I have tried to manually add SSR for the index page but no joy.

Anyone who faced similar issue or just generally knows better Nuxt/Vuetify having ideas how to avoid this slow loading of Vuetify color settings? What is the correct way to implement vuetify to avoid this extended loading time of css when static deploying?

**Note that this slow loading of styles does not occur when using npm run dev (ie nuxt dev) or npm run start (ie nuxt start).**

nuxt.config.js (omitted unrelated properties):

```
import i18n from './config/i18n'
export default {
    target: 'static',
    debug: true,
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        host: process.env.PROD === 'True' ? '0.0.0.0' : 'localhost'
    },
    vue: {
        config: {
            productionTip: true,
            devtools: true
        }
    },
    render: {
        ssr: true, // Enable SSR for the entire application
        static: {
            // Configure SSR for specific routes
            // In this case, only the index page ("/") will use SSR
            match: /^\/$/,
        },
    },
    dev: false,
    // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
    css: [
        '@/assets/styles/global.scss',
        '@/assets/fonts/font.css',
        '@/assets/styles/style.css',
    ],

    // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
    components: false,

    // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
    modules: [
        [ '@nuxtjs/vuetify', { } ],
    ],
    vuetify: {
        treeShake: true,
        theme: {
            themes: {
                options: {customProperties: true},
                light: {
                    primary: '#0073ff',
                    accent: '#f56302',
                    secondary: '#19BADF',
                    dark: '#001c76',
                },
            }
        },
        iconfont: 'mdi'
    },
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and solved by closing SSR (may not a good solution but took effect)

Comment: @KaiKai thank you for your reply. I tried with         ```[ '@nuxtjs/vuetify', { ssr: false} ]```, but nothing changed. Also it would be such a pity to literally lose the only thing nuxt is good for - ssr. Without it it is just another unnecessary level of abstraction on top of Vue. Any other way to force noSSR mode?